# This is undefined on Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I searched and all what I found is that the problem was on arrow functions, but I am not using arrow functions..

```
  data(){
   return{
     id_list : this.$route.params.list_id, 
     people: ['john', 'Sara']
   },

   },created(){
     this.people// this is undefined
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in data().

```
data(){
    return{
      id_list : this.$route.params.list_id, 
      people: []
    }
  },
```

I was not using $route any more so it was undefined and It broke the vue instance.